# google adwords php client lib v201702

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I am using Google Adwords API v201702 for php client lib and [try to accessing an API on behalf of clients](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/wiki/API-access-on-behalf-of-your-clients-(web-flow))

I have successfully created $oauth2 data , by using below code

```
use Google\Auth\OAuth2;

session_start();

$oauth2 = new OAuth2([
    'authorizationUri' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth',
    'tokenCredentialUri' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    'redirectUri' => '****',
    'clientId' => '****',
    'clientSecret' => '****',
    'scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords'
]);
```

My issue is when i pass an array into scope result page become blank , Please help me how can i pass an array to scope for google adwords php client lib for getting all **CustomerServices** data .
Please also describe the way to get **clientCustomerId** using **AccessToken** in Google Adwords API v201702.

Thanks all.

Comment: The Google Adwords API v201702 does not exists anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add array by doing like this:

```
   'scope' => array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile')
```